# I need to put this label I've created in/ or right next to the textbox. Any ideas please?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and now I'm stuck on how to put the label in/next to the text box to give the perception of 1 element please:

**HTML**

```
<div style="position: relative; float: left;  margin-left: 12px;">
    <input type="text" class="theInput" />
    <label class="theLabel">$    &nbsp;  |</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.theInput {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: #333333; 
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #E4EBED;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fff; 
    padding-left:45px;

}


.theLabel {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none; 
    color: #333333; 
    outline: none; 
    width: 34px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    margin-left:-106px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor:default;
}
```

This is the desired : [final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPnvp.png)

Answer (score 2):

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/d5ca4z88/

You should use the label tag like so:

```
<label>Label Name: <input type="text" class="theInput"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (Adjust your needs):

**CSS**

```
.theInput {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: #333333;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #E4EBED;
    border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-left:45px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
.theLabel {
    position:relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    color: #333333;
    outline: none;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor:default;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/Vbr9d/214/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/u5j9xq4x/

**HTML**

```
<div style="position: relative; float: left;  margin-left: 12px;">
    <div class="price">
        <label class="theLabel">&euro;</label>
        <input type="text" class="theInput" value="000">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.theInput {
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    max-width: 70px;
}

.price {
    border: 3px solid #333333;
}

.theLabel {
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```